# textfield with permanent text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a textfield in which I want permanent text to display "x10". I then want the user to be able to input a number to that same textfield, but to the left of "x10". I was wondering if it would be possible to permanently place a string inside the textfield. This is the closest I can come up with so far, but this approach is littered with problems.

```
textField.text = [self.exerciseWeight stringByAppendingString:@"x10"];
```

I have had success using labels inside of the textfield, but I would prefer using a string, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're asking now. There's a built in `rightView` property on `UITextField`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Use it like this with the `rightViewMode` set to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
label.text = @"x 10";

UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.rightView = label;
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: But the user does interact with it. I want everything inside of one textfield.

Comment: Aaron is probably right. The easiest thing to do is to put a label to the right of your text field. It'll probably be a lot clearer as to what's going on as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll just stick with the label.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the `UITextField` and it looks like there's a better approach.